# Как заполнить большую таблицу MySQL c помощью Java + JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER (USER_ID, USERNAME) VALUES (1,'mkyong')";
```

Только чтобы вместо `1` и `mkyong` были переменные ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO здесь больше подойдет таки `PreparedStatement` совместно с Batch - [смотрите например](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/)

Answer (score 2):

почитай что такое Prepared Statement, [здесь](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/) например.

```
String selectSQL = "SELECT USER_ID, USERNAME FROM DBUSER WHERE USER_ID = ?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1001);
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL );
```